# Wall post shows "n/a"

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem that's been bugging me for a while now. I have a page with a `Facebook Like` button on it. When the visitor clicks on it, everything is working as it should. The user first logs in her `Facebook` account, and the right information is showing in the little `iFrame` that pops up. It has correct headline, url, image, and the possibility to add some text to the post.

But once posted on `Facebook`, the wall post doesn't show the description, instead it shows four rows with the text `n/a`. How come?

Some additional information:

- I have set the followwing fields in the head section of the html, and
  the `Facebook debugger tool` scrapes the correct information: `og:title`,
  `og:description`, `og:image`, `og:url`, `og:locale`, `og:type`
- Also, it always works for me and some others when liking it, but not
  when person X or Y tries to share it, so it's kind of sporadic...
- I use the `Facebook js sdk`.
- In the `Facebook debugger tool` I get this warning: `fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.` But I have read somewhere that this shouldn't be necessary in my case.
- The description sometimes contains characters like `Å`, `Ä` and `Ö`.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide URL to the page?

Comment: Okay, there seems to be something with languages. When i change my Facebook settings from english (which it works on) to swedish, it start showing n/a. This guy seems to have the same problem:[another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422580/description-of-like-for-dutch-description-becomes-niet-beschikbaar). I also found a bug report on [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/117276831773917?browse=search_5107c82c94f4d4c36274016). I'm afraid i can't supply you with an url at this point.