# Description of Like for Dutch, description becomes: Niet Beschikbaar

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a site, registered as an app on facebook (with fb login). The site is in English, and has og:title og:description app id etc in the meta for the pages.

If people Like a page on the site, the description and title is nicely put on their timeline.

But, if they use Facebook in Dutch, they get the title on their timeline, but the description of the article they shared is replaced by 4 times "niet beschikbaar" (that means "not available")

I tried Facebook in German, but there the English description is used....

Is this a Facebook bug? Or is it me? And why only (as it seems) the "error" for fb users using Dutch?

Comment: That's strange. Could be a caching issue. Could you provide a link for that page? Subsequently you can use the debugger to test the URL yourself: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Hi, did you fix this problem already ?

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same issue. The tools/debug lint from facebook does not see any errors.

**There is a bug reported, see:**

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/326334460804515?browse=search_51130494eb59c1a06817175

There is no solution there, hope there will be soon.

More information:

Aggregations

Some components of the Aggregations are translated by Facebook, and others are translated by your app.

In general, objects are translated by your app, and strings associated with actions are translated by Facebook.

**Aggregation**

An Aggregation's title and all of its caption text are translated through the standard Facebook Internationalization process. References to object title and object descriptions are translated by your app.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/internationalization/

I really think it is  a bug in the translations.

Greetings,

Kevin Hoekman